# Did something change in the way of implementing UITableViewDataSource methods?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, cell, xcode11

Recently a few things might have changed in iOS development.
Instead of AppDelegate's didFinishLauching now we have to set up our window and root VC in SceneDelegate. (No storyboard ,please!)OK, that is not so difficult, and not so different.
 But now it looks I can't even dequeue cells on my UITableViewDatasource now. Something as simple as that! What am I doing wrong again? I set the number of rows to 80 just to make sure, something will appear, but no luck there. I get the systemTeal colored tableView inside my ViewController (embedded in a navigationController), and that' it. Any Ideas?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let cellId = "cellId"

    lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tb = UITableView()
        tb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tb
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        setupTableView()
    }

    fileprivate func  setupTableView() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        tableView.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 80 }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId)!
        cell.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        cell.textLabel?.text = "cell: \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 50 }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { 1 }
}
```

Comment: What goes wrong, do you get an error?

Comment: No cells, no error :(

Comment: You're missing `tableView.dataSource = self`

Comment: You don't seem to have set the `UITableView#dataSource` property (you've set the delegate)

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I am probably too exhausted and should take a rest :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides setting the delegate, you should also set the data source:

```
tableView.dataSource = self
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a custom `ViewController` *containing* a `tableView` (instead of the `UITableViewController`), You, must remember to set the `DataSource` (and `Delegate` if needed). In this case, one of the best places to take the delegation and data source is in the closure:

```
lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tb = UITableView()
    tb.dataSource = self
    tb.delegate = self
    tb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tb
}()
```